# How to sort this list in Python?

Tags: python, list

[ {'time':33}, {'time':11}, {'time':66} ]

How to sort by the "time" element, DESC.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = sorted(l, key=itemgetter('time'), reverse=True)
```

Or:

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda a: a['time'], reverse=True)
```

output:

```
[{'time': 66}, {'time': 33}, {'time': 11}]
```

If you don't want to keep the original order you can use `your_list.sort` which modifies the original list instead of creating a copy like `sorted(your_list)`

```
l.sort(key=lambda a: a['time'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: the operator.itemgetter version is preferred. It has one less function call for each element.

Comment: @nosklo, itemgetter actually returns a function that works almost the same as lambda a: a['time'] so there isn't really much of a difference from this prospective. Both methods involves a function call for each element.